# c# equivalent to php associative array?

Tags: c#, .net, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915347/c-sharp-associative-array)

ive decided to learn c# recently. ive done some php before. i see c# has dictionaries. thats equivalent to an associative array in php right? as far as i can tell the dictionary doesnt maintain insertion order like php associative arrays right?  is there some other equivalent i should use if insertion order is important?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary doesn't *guarantee* to preserve insertion order, so no: you can't rely on that (although it is hard to force it to break this). If insertion order is important, you would need to create a hybrid class, perhaps encapsulating a `List<T>` for the inserted order, and a `Dictionary<TKey,T>` for the indexing.

Comment: Java has one (LinkedHashMap). There's really no equivalent in C#?

Comment: @cletus: No. there's really no equivalent in the core .NET framework. @Marc: It's not that hard to force it. I can't remember it offhand, admittedly... it's in a post somewhere, I think.

Comment: if you tend to get ordering with a hashtable it implies your hash function is crap and your O(1) is at risk. you should have close to random insertion position for any bucket...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Power Collections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections). I believe they have implementations that would suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class in the `System.Collections.Specialized` namespace, but it's unfortunately not generic.

There is no built-in, generic dictionary class that preserves insertion order.  If insertion order is really important, you'll have to roll your own or check out a third party implementation (as Marc & Kent suggested).

Answer (score 1):

PHP associative arrays are converted to type XmlRpcStruct.  See the [XML-RPC spec.](http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec/)

In C#, use XmlRpcStruct or struct to represent PHP associative arrays.

This is a tested solution, not an offhand suggestion.